# Сортировка двусвязного списка: дублируются данные

Tags: c++, c, сортировка, списки, двусвязный-список

В файле лежит массив элементов структуры contact, из файла данные читаются в массив, а из него формируется двусвязный список, отсортированный по полю `sname` по алфавиту. В моей реализации при выводе данные отсортированы, но дублируются. Через отладчик ошибку не нашла. В чём может быть ошибка?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

struct contact
{
    char nomer[50];
    char adress[50];
    char sname[50];
};

struct Node
{
    char nomer[50];
    char adress[50];
    char sname[50];
    Node *next, *prev;
};

typedef Node *PNode;

PNode CreateNode(contact buf)
{
    PNode NewNode = new Node;
    strcpy(NewNode->nomer, buf.nomer);
    strcpy(NewNode->adress, buf.adress);
    strcpy(NewNode->sname, buf.sname);
    NewNode->next = NULL;
    NewNode->prev = NULL;
    return NewNode;
}

void AddNode(PNode &Head, PNode &Tail, PNode NewNode)
{
    NewNode->next = NULL;
    NewNode->prev = Tail;
    if (Tail) Tail->next = NewNode;
    Tail = NewNode;
    if (!Head) Head = Tail;
}

void AddFirst(PNode &Head, PNode NewNode)
{
    NewNode->next = Head;
    Head = NewNode;
}    

void AddAfter(PNode &Head, PNode &Tail, PNode p, PNode NewNode)
{
    NewNode->next = p->next; 
    NewNode->prev = p;
    p->next->prev = NewNode; 
    p->next = NewNode;
}
void AddBefore(PNode &Head, PNode &Tail, PNode p, PNode NewNode)
{
    if (Head == p)
    {
        NewNode->next = Head;
        Head = NewNode;
    }
    else
    {
        NewNode->prev = p->prev; 
        NewNode->next = p;
        p->prev->next = NewNode; 
        p->prev = NewNode;
    }
}    

void ShowTwoLinkedList(PNode Head)
{
    PNode p = Head;
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", p->sname);
        p = p->next;
    }
    fflush(stdin);
    getchar();
}

void AddAndSort(contact buf, PNode Head, PNode Tail)
{
    PNode NewNode = CreateNode(buf);
    PNode p = Head;
    while (p->next && (strcmp(p->sname, NewNode->sname) < 0))
        p = p->next;
    if ((strcmp(p->sname, NewNode->sname) < 0))
        AddAfter(Head, Tail, p, NewNode);
    else
        AddBefore(Head, Tail, p, NewNode);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    int rezh;
    PNode Head = NULL;
    PNode Tail = NULL;
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("telbook.dat", "r+b");
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    int size = ftell(f);
    int kol_el = size / sizeof(contact);
    contact *buf = new contact[kol_el];
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fread(buf, sizeof(contact), kol_el, f);
    fclose(f);
    for (int i = 0; i < kol_el; i++)
    {
        PNode NewNode = CreateNode(buf[i]);
        AddNode(Head, Tail, NewNode);
    }    

    do{
        system("cls");
        const int NotUsed = system("color 03");
        printf("Выберите действие:\n");
        printf("1.Показать список.\n");
        printf("2.Создание+сортировка.\n");
        printf("3.Выйти из программы.\n");
        scanf_s("%d", &rezh);
        switch (rezh)
        {
        case 1:
        {
            ShowTwoLinkedList(Head);
            break;
        }

        case 2:
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < kol_el; i++)
                AddAndSort(buf[i], Head, Tail);
            break;
        }    

        }
    } while (rezh != 3);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

### Изменённый код

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<cstdlib>
#include<string.h>
#include<iostream>

struct contact
{
    char nomer[50];
    char adress[50];
    char sname[50];
};

struct Node
{
    char nomer[50];
    char adress[50];
    char sname[50];
    Node *next, *prev;
};typedef Node *PNode;

PNode CreateNode(contact buf)
{
    PNode NewNode = new Node;
    strcpy(NewNode->nomer, buf.nomer);
    strcpy(NewNode->adress, buf.adress);
    strcpy(NewNode->sname, buf.sname);
    NewNode->next = NULL;
    NewNode->prev = NULL;
    return NewNode;
}    

void AddNode(PNode &Head, PNode &Tail, PNode NewNode)
{
    NewNode->next = NULL;
    NewNode->prev = Tail;
    if (Tail) Tail->next = NewNode;
    Tail = NewNode;
    if (!Head) Head = Tail;
}    

void AddFirst(PNode &Head, PNode NewNode)
{
    NewNode->next = Head;
    Head = NewNode;
}

void AddAfter(PNode &Head, PNode &Tail, PNode p, PNode NewNode)
{
    NewNode->next = p->next;
    NewNode->prev = p;
    p->next->prev = NewNode;
    p->next = NewNode;
}
void AddBefore(PNode &Head, PNode &Tail, PNode p, PNode NewNode)
{
    if (Head == p)
    {
        NewNode->next = Head;
        Head = NewNode;
    }
    else
    {
        NewNode->prev = p->prev;
        NewNode->next = p;
        p->prev->next = NewNode;
        p->prev = NewNode;
    }
    }    

void ShowTwoLinkedList(PNode Head)
{
    PNode p = Head;
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", p->sname);
        p = p->next;
    }
    fflush(stdin);
    getchar();
}    

void AddAndSort(contact buf, PNode Head, PNode Tail)
{
    PNode NewNode = CreateNode(buf);
    PNode p = Head;
    while (p->next && (strcmp(p->sname, NewNode->sname) < 0))
        p = p->next;
    if ((strcmp(p->sname, NewNode->sname) < 0))
        AddAfter(Head, Tail, p, NewNode);
    else
        AddBefore(Head, Tail, p, NewNode);
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    int rezh;
    PNode Head = NULL;
    PNode Tail = NULL;
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("telbook.dat", "r+b");
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    int size = ftell(f);
    int kol_el = size / sizeof(contact);
    contact *buf = new contact[kol_el];
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fread(buf, sizeof(contact), kol_el, f);
    fclose(f);

    do {
        system("cls");
        const int NotUsed = system("color 03");
        printf("Выберите действие:\n");
        printf("1.Показать список.\n");
        printf("2.Создание+сортировка.\n");
        printf("3.Выйти из программы.\n");
        scanf_s("%d", &rezh);
        switch (rezh)
        {
        case 1:
        {
            ShowTwoLinkedList(Head);
            break;
        }

        case 2:
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < kol_el; i++)
                AddAndSort(buf[i], Head, Tail);
            break;
        }    

        }
    } while (rezh != 3);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы сначала в `main` вносите узлы в список

```
for (int i = 0; i < kol_el; i++)
{
    PNode NewNode = CreateNode(buf[i]);
    AddNode(Head, Tail, NewNode);
}
```

А потом еще раз их дублируете перед сортировкой:

```
for (int i = 0; i < kol_el; i++)
    AddAndSort(buf[i], Head, Tail);
```

Вот и получаете два списка... Вы еще раз отсортируйте - три будет :)

Comment: Убрала добавление из мейна, при запуске функции вылезает ошибка "нарушение доступа для чтения. p было nullptr." можете пояснить с чем связана ошибка и как её исправить?

Comment: Пытаетесь обратиться к чему-то по нулевому адресу. А точнее - увы, не телепат, и как вы исправили код и что там происходит - на расстоянии не вижу :)

Comment: Добавила изменённый код в описание вопроса

Comment: А что у вас в файле `telbook.dat`?

Comment: Тогда это вы проскакиваете. Но потом в `void AddAndSort(contact buf, PNode Head, PNode Tail)` вы передаете `Head` - нулевой указатель. Присваиваете его значение указателю `p     PNode p = Head;` и пытаетесь его использовать:   `while (p->next && (strcmp(p->sname, NewNode->sname) < 0))` Вот и всё...

Answer (score 0):

Вместо функции AddAndSort(она дублирует данные), сделай другую OnlySort.

```
void OnlySort(contact buf, PNode Head, PNode Tail)
{
    PNode NewNode = CreateNode(buf);
    PNode p = Head;
    while (p->next && (strcmp(p->sname, NewNode->sname) < 0))
        p = p->next;
}
```

Comment: при такой замене сортировки не произойдёт